# ng2 bootstrap modal cannot be closed when onclick function is not in button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a page which has a list of items. And by clicking on each item, a ng2-bootstrap modal will be triggered to show detail info about the item. But I found a issue when I try to use (click)="lgModal.show()" outside the button. the Modal cannot be closed by either clicking outside the overlay or clicking the little x(cross) button. The only way to close the modal is to press 'Escape' key. 
Here is the code sample:

```
<li (click)="lgModal.show()" *ngFor="let item of Items"> {{ item }}
    <div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Large modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Is there a way that i can get away with this button and move (onclick) outside the button.
Large modal

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `data-dismiss` attribute

Replace

```
<button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>\
```

with

```
<button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
```

Comment: it does not work for me... still cannot close the modal.

Comment: can you make a plunkr or jsfiddle for this?